# what's different between lib and lib-devel in yum?

Tags: yum

I'm compiling a software that depends on `libpcap`,so I `yum install libpcap`,but when I `./configure` it still reports can't find libpcap,so I run `yum install libpcap-devel` and this time it works.

My question is,what's the difference and what exactly was `./configure` looking for when it says `libpcap` not found?

Answer (score 2):

"lib" contains the things your program needs to run (the ".so" file).  "lib-devel" contains the things your program needs to compile (the header files).

Comment: How does the `./configure` know where the header files are?

Comment: Sometimes the `-devel` libraries also include a program called `lib-config` that will print out where all the development files are.  For example, to find out where the Apache Portable Runtime header files are, run `apr-1-config --includes`

Comment: But how does `./configure` know about that?

Comment: I'd guess `./configure` tries to call `apr-1-config` and if it fails, it assumes it's not installed.